# Get event that fire a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I've got a simple function:

```
function view() {
  alert('blabla')
}
```

I can call this method with `onmouseover`:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="view()">call</a>
```

or by another function:

```
  function wrapperView() {
     view()
  }
```

Can I know the event that fires my `view()` function without passing another parameter to my function?

Comment: What's wrong with passing an argument to your function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use caller.name Refered by RajaPrabhu

```
function view() {
  alert(arguments.callee.caller.name)
}

function wrapperView() {
     view()
}

wrapperView();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YPn52/1/)

Comment: `without pass another parameter to my function?` - OP

Comment: wrapperView() how to call this funciton

Comment: This isn't answering your question. "can i know the _event_". This is giving you the function name. The other answers are answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

The `view` function will be passed an argument automatically:

```
function view(event) {
  console.log(event);
  alert('blabla');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get `event` object without passing it, by bindind `mouseover` event using jQuery :

HTML :

```
  <a href="#">call</a>
```

jQuery :

```
 $(function(){
    $('a[href="#"]').mouseover(function(e){
        // here e is event object
        alert('event '+e);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

arguments.callee is depricated in js 1.5
Could you please refer the below link

https: //developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee